# Can I use Java to upload file to AWS S3 from SMB

Tags: amazon-s3, smbj

I want to directly upload file from SMB to S3(AWS) use Java.
Could you give me some advice to fix this issue.
(Not download to local and upload to S3)

Answer (score 0):

You can get an InputStream from the SMB File object, and an OutputStream to the S3 bucket File. This will however traverse through your own machine (i.e. SMB --InputStream--> Your app --OutputStream--> S3).